# After Syria entered civil war, did B1/B2 or Schengen visas of Syrians became useless?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, b1-b2-visas, syrian-citizens

Say you are a Syrian citizen. You have a 10 year US B1/B2 visa and 5 year multi entry Schengen visa. You visited EU and US as a tourist before many times without any issues. Your country enters civil war. Does that make your visas useless?

Looking forward to an answer from a Syrian citizen based on his experience (or another similar country like maybe Libya and Iraq).

Comment: I’m not sure that entering a civil war inherently means visas become useless.

Comment: There's no inherent meaning to anything @Traveller

Answer (score 10):

> Does that make your visas useless?

**No**, it does not.

While I am not a Syrian national (my father's father was), I have many friends and colleagues who are Syrians, I see them go to Europe all the time since the war started. One of my closest friends used her Schengen visa to enter Europe a few years ago and the visa was issued before the war.

However, the war has been going for almost 10 years now (next March it will be 10 years), there are no Schengen visas valid for that period, and there might be a very few Syrian citizens with valid US visas issued before the war, most likely none since Syrians almost always get a single entry US visas (B1/B2).

Finally, citizens of Syria and some other countries [were not allowed to enter the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13769) except for some rare exceptions from January 2017 until January 2021 even if they held a valid visa, but even that did not invalidate their visas.

Comment: That's good news for people whose country enters a civil war. I also wonder if it works the same way for citizens of Iraq, Libya and Afghanistan

Comment: One has to be aware that having a visa does not guarantee entry. With a visa you can approach the border and ask permission to enter the country. It can still be refused. When your country is at war the immigration officer may decide to not let you in on the assumption that you probably will not be eager to leave again...

Comment: The main restriction is rather that not many Syrians would hold circulation visas, especially if they reside in Syria. As explained in the answer, the US is even stricter but it's not like everybody gets Schengen visas easily either or would have had a reason to apply for one beforehand.

Comment: @KristvanBesien In that case, you always have the option of claiming refugee status then and there (in the EU at least). A border guard may be tempted to refuse entry on the assumption that the person doesn't know their rights but usually if their intent is really to immigrate because of the situation in the country, it becomes moot. The visa is most useful to get past the check at your departure airport and get yourself a chance to reach the entry check.

Comment: It's because the EU does not want people to come and claim refugee status that they will try to keep you from even boarding a plane to the EU in the first place... Sad, but true.

Comment: @KristvanBesien So your visas become useless then?

Comment: @Relaxed "In that case, you always have the option of claiming refugee status then and there (in the EU at least)." Lol. Do you work in immigration or are you an immigrant from a country like Syria?

Comment: @KristvanBesien Indeed and that's precisely where having a visa makes a difference.